# Using Gradle Spoon Plugin to launch tests in specific location

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso, spoon

I am having problem to find documentation how could I solve that case.

I am capable of launching small/medium/large tests with:

```
./gradlew spoonSmall
./gradlew spoonMedium
./gradlew spoonLarge
```

Or launching specific tests with usage of this setup:

```
spoon {
    (...)

    if (project.hasProperty('spoonClassName')) {
        className = project.spoonClassName

        if (project.hasProperty('spoonMethodName')) {
            methodName = project.spoonMethodName
        }
    }
}
```

I can launch specific file:

```
./gradlew spoon -PspoonClassName=com.package.tests.MyTest;
```

What I am interested in is a possibility to launch all tests located in:

```
./gradlew spoon -PspoonClassName=com.package.tests
```

package. Either method is fine. Some parameter to bash console or maybe way to create my own annotation and launch by something like ./gradlew spoonMyTests.

I am grateful for suggestions/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official docs:

> There are numerous ways to run a specific test, or set of tests. You
>   can use the Spoon --size, --class-name or --method-name options, or
>   you can use the --e option to pass arguments to the instrumentation
>   runner, e.g.
>
> --e package=com.mypackage.unit_tests

The following command should work when executing Spoon directly from command line (not from the gradle task)

```
java -jar spoon-runner-1.1.9-jar-with-dependencies.jar \
    --apk ExampleApp-debug.apk \
    --test-apk ExampleApp-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk \
    --e package=com.package.tests
```

You need to find a way to pass this extra param to the Spoon gradle plugin.

### UPDATE

From the [official doc](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin#custom-instrumentation-arguments) of *Spoon Gradle plugin*:

> Custom instrumentation arguments
>
> Use the instrumentationArgs property on spoon extension to pass custom
>   parameters to your tests:
>
> spoon {   instrumentationArgs = ["foo=bar", "name=value"] }

In your case, this should look like the following:

```
spoon {   
    instrumentationArgs = ["package=com.package.tests"] 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Seems legit, but don't know why I receive error: 

Problem configuring task :app:spoon from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--e'.

Comment: @F1sher Yes, because this is a command option for the pure Spoon (not the gradle plugin). I've updated my answer

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for your help and very fast response/looking into my matter. It works :) Could I have one question more? Can I add 'apk' and 'test-apk' also as an argument? I will need to specify that one too.

Comment: @F1sher This is what you can set at extension level: https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/stanfy/spoon/gradle/SpoonExtension.groovy I think you have to pass it as an  *intrumentationArgs* (just like the package name)